# Не могу понять, как правильно прописать js в php

Tags: php, javascript

Такая ситуация, когда добавляешь картинку в пост, то выводится картинка и краткое описание, если картинка не добавлена, то выводится вместо неё заглушка.
 В `php` я убрал вывод заглушки и теперь хочу сделать так, чтобы когда картинка не добавляется, то описание растягивалось на всю ширину.
Вот код:

```
if ( ! isset( $barcelona_placeholder_img ) || false === $barcelona_placeholder_img ) {
            $barcelona_placeholder_img = 'assets/images/placeholders/' . ( $size == 'full' ? 'barcelona-full' : $size ) . '-pthumb.jpg';

            if ( is_readable( BARCELONA_SERVER_PATH . $barcelona_placeholder_img ) ) {
                @list( $barcelona_width, $barcelona_height ) = getimagesize( BARCELONA_SERVER_PATH . $barcelona_placeholder_img );
            }

            $barcelona_placeholder_img = BARCELONA_THEME_PATH . $barcelona_placeholder_img;

        }
```

Я знаю что нужно подключить к этому `js` что бы он при отсутствии картинки выводил другой стиль или присваивал другой клас, но не знаю как это сделать

Пожалуйста подскажите.

Comment: вы можете это сделать и на пхп. если нет картинки в вью где выводите текст блоку дайте еще один клас

Comment: В том то и проблема, что я не знаю куда это вставить, я нашёл код который это выводит убрал строчку выводящую заглушку, и теперь не знаю что и куда надо вписать что бы применялись другие стили

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно написать код по такому принципу, можно обойтись без JS

`<a class="<?= $image ? 'first_class' : 'second_class' ?>"></a>`

Этот код равнозначен такому:

`<a class="<?php if ($image) { echo 'first_class'; } else { echo 'second_class'; } ?>"></a>`

Вам осталось прописать правильные if условия и html разметку.